# Missing File Extension "tsx" for Typescript React Project

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm trying to configure a CRA project with Typescript eslinting, and I've run into an eslint issue which says

`Missing file extension for "tsx" for "./App"`

I already tried several solutions posted on stackoverflow, but none were successful I would appreciate any recommendations. I already tried setting the proper extensions manually in the rules section , as well as in settings.

// eslintr.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
      "project":["./tsconfig.json"],
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "react-hooks"],
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [2, "single"],
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["off"],
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [".tsx", ".jsx", ".js", ".ts"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {
        "alwaysTryTypes": true,
        "paths": "./tsconfig.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.5",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  }
```

Comment: Is the file extension for your App `.tsx`?

Comment: Oops sorry to include it, but the error shows up in the index.tsx file where the app file is imported. However it cant import due to the mentioned error.

Comment: did you import it as  "./App.tsx" in your index.tsx

Comment: I can't import it as that, because I get an error that an import path cannot end with a tsx  extension.

Comment: Try adding this to "rules": {
   "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
   ]
}

Comment: Already have that in my rules

Comment: Thanks anyways, my issue ended up getting resolved by itself. The issue no longer appears

Comment: @sidc the rule you commented worked on my end, thanks for that =]